# Adding validations via submit button

Tags: jquery, validation, cakephp

I am using Cakephp and JQuery in my application.
   I have created the form using

```
<?php
 echo $form->create('Result',array('action'=>"submit/$formid"));

 foreach ($viewfields as $r): 
 echo $form->input($r['Attribute']['label'], array('id'=>$r['Attribute']['id'],'name'=>$r['Attribute']['label'],'type'=>'text'));
  endforeach; 
 echo $form->end('submit');?>
```

This will creates a Form with id for eg...ResultSubmit1Form    where 1 is the formid

When i click on the submit button it submits the data correctly.
  But i want to add JQuery validations like none of the fields has to be empty .

I tried it with some examples But itt didnt works .How can i do so.....Please suggest me..

Edit:

I tried it with

```
  $("#ResultSubmit/$formidForm").submit(function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
  /* do validation of fields */
  if($("#"+<?=$r['Attribute']['id'];?>).fieldValue()==""){alert("Fill in  "+"<?=$r['Attribute']['label'];?>");
            $("#"+<?=$r['Attribute']['id'];?>).focus();
     }
  });
```

But nothing works ,this didnt enters into event at all..

Answer (score 3):

#### Updated Response...

You're attempting to mix PHP with Javascript, that won't work. Take this line for instance:

```
$("#ResultSubmit/$formidForm")
```

You're printing this out as plain-text js-code, meaning `$formidForm` is not understood to be a variable containing a value, it's handled as "dollar-sign formidform." If you wanted to print the PHP-value, you'd have to do something like:

```
$formidForm = "#userDetails";
$("<?php print $formidForm; ?>") /* $("#userDetails") */
```

Now that it's within `<?php` and `?>`, your server knows to interpret that particular part as PHP, and not plain-text.

As for the rest of your js-code, what does it look like when you copy/paste it from the webpage for the viewer?

#### Original Response...

You would bind the check to the .submit() event of the form:

```
$("#myForm").submit(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  /* do validation of fields */
});
```

You could benefit from a utilizing a [Validation Plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) too.

Answer (score 1):

I am using jquery [validation plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) and its [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) is also nice. It works like charm to me